# Force refresh of CSS files

Tags: android, css, webview

I have a `WebView` that loads HTML files from within the private data of my app. I load those files from a server, then saves them to the private data folder. They come with JavaScript files, and CSS files, images, etc. So my `WebView` then display those HTML files just fine.

My problem is when I modify the content of those files on my server, and then download those files again in the app (first I made sure all files were deleted from the private data folder) and open the `WebView`, everything is updated except for the CSS files, the style remains the same. The quickest solution that I found to force the CSS files to be updated in the `WebView` is to delete all content for the app (in the settings) and then download the files again.

Note: I don't want to clear all data like history or whatever since I am using local storage on the `WebView`, but clearing resources is fine, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a timestamp or unique value to the end of the css filename when calling it if possible.  I use this method within my webapp although i append the timestamp using php, im sure it can be done in html with JS also  using event.timeStamp.

e.g

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.css?timestamp=<? echo $timestamp?>">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code with myWebView to force re-load my css files:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE forces your html files to be loaded from the network. Doc: "Don't use the cache, load from the network. Use with setCacheMode(int)."

Comment: Works perfect. Loads CSS immediately.